# Show empty groups in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am trying to display a ListBox that has items grouped by a property named `Status`. That is easy enough using `CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions`, but I run into problems when I want to show empty groups like this:

[image: List box with empty groups]

I discovered how to add Group names to a group description but they are not unique. Running this code displays all statuses:

```
var collectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("Source");
var groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Status");
foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status)))
{
    groupDescription.GroupNames.Add(name);
}
collectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

but all the groups with items in are repeated. Also these manually created groups do not have items inside and are a total duplicates different from the groups WPF created:

[image]

I figured I could listen to the `CollectionChanged` on the `GroupNames` `ObservableCollection` and add or remove these custom group names manually but `GroupNames` is always empty (unless the groups names are added manually as in the above snippet) so `CollectionChanged` is never fired.

Here is the code without the custom GroupName logic:

C#:

```
    public enum Status
    {
        Present,
        Sick,
        Vacation,
        BusinessTrip
    }
    
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; }
        
        public Status Status { get; }
        
        public ViewModel(string id, Status status)
        {
            Id = id;
            Status = status;
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new List<ViewModel> {
                new ("Zack", Status.Present),
                new ("Adam", Status.Sick),
                new ("Matt", Status.Present),
                new ("Nick", Status.Present),
                new ("Boss", Status.Vacation),
                new ("Phil", Status.Vacation)
            };

            var collectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("Source");
            var groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Status");
            collectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="EmptyGroups.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Source" Source="{Binding}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Source}}">
            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander>
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>    
                                                <TextBlock Margin="10" Background="Aqua" Text="{Binding ItemCount}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="50 10" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListBox.GroupStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any ideas? I have a feeling there is a different and better way of getting this `Empty Group` feature.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, tho it still feels hacky...

Create a class that inherits from CollectionViewSource:

```
public class CustomCollectionViewSource : CollectionViewSource
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AllGroupNamesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "AllGroupNames", typeof(List<string>), typeof(CustomCollectionViewSource),
        new PropertyMetadata(new List<string>(), OnAllGroupNamesChanged));

    private static void OnAllGroupNamesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        ((CustomCollectionViewSource) d).UpdateGroupNames();

    public List<string> AllGroupNames
    {
        get => (List<string>) GetValue(AllGroupNamesProperty);
        set => SetValue(AllGroupNamesProperty, value);
    }

    public CustomCollectionViewSource()
    {
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor
            .FromProperty(ViewProperty, typeof(CustomCollectionViewSource))
            .AddValueChanged(this, OnViewChanged);
    }

    private void OnViewChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => UpdateGroupNames();

    private void OnViewCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) => UpdateGroupNames();

    private void UpdateGroupNames()
    {
        if (View == null) return;
        if (View.GroupDescriptions.Count != 1)
            throw new Exception("CustomCollectionViewSource must have exactly one GroupDescription!");

        View.CollectionChanged -= OnViewCollectionChanged;
        try
        {
            var groupDescription = View.GroupDescriptions.First();
            groupDescription.GroupNames.Clear();
            var names = View.Groups.Cast<CollectionViewGroup>().Select(cvg => cvg.Name.ToString());
            foreach (var s in AllGroupNames.Except(names))
                groupDescription.GroupNames.Add(s);
        }
        finally
        {
            View.CollectionChanged += OnViewCollectionChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in instead of `CollectionViewSource`:

```
<emptyGroups:CustomCollectionViewSource x:Key="Source" Source="{Binding}">
    <emptyGroups:CustomCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
         <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Status"/>
    </emptyGroups:CustomCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</emptyGroups:CustomCollectionViewSource>
```

Then there are two ways to specify the groups:

1. Assign them manually in code behind:

   ```
   var collectionViewSource = (CustomCollectionViewSource)FindResource("Source");
   foreach (var status in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status)))
   {
       collectionViewSource.AllGroupNames.Add(status);    
   }
   ```
2. Use the XAML:

   ```
   <emptyGroups:CustomCollectionViewSource x:Key="Source" Source="{Binding}">
        <emptyGroups:CustomCollectionViewSource.AllGroupNames>
            <system:String>Present</system:String>
            <system:String>Sick</system:String>
            <system:String>Vacation</system:String> 
            <system:String>BusinessTrip</system:String>
        </emptyGroups:CustomCollectionViewSource.AllGroupNames>
        <emptyGroups:CustomCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Status"/>
        </emptyGroups:CustomCollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
   </emptyGroups:CustomCollectionViewSource>
   ```

One problem is the empty groups are always displayed on top of the groups with items in. This can be fixed by setting `groupDescription.CustomSort` in `CustomCollectionViewSource` inside `UpdateGroupNames` :

```
  private void UpdateGroupNames() {
    if (View == null) return;
    if (View.GroupDescriptions.Count != 1)
      throw new Exception("CustomCollectionViewSource must have exactly one GroupDescription!");

    View.CollectionChanged -= OnViewCollectionChanged;
    try {
      var groupDescription = View.GroupDescriptions.First();
      groupDescription.GroupNames.Clear();
      var names = View.Groups.Cast<CollectionViewGroup>().Select(cvg => cvg.Name.ToString());
      foreach (var s in AllGroupNames.Except(names))
        groupDescription.GroupNames.Add(s);

      groupDescription.CustomSort = new SortByGroupCount(); // Add if you want to order the groups by items.
    } finally {
      View.CollectionChanged += OnViewCollectionChanged;
    }
  }
```

Here is `SortByGroupCount`:

```
public class SortByGroupCount : IComparer {
  public int Compare(object x, object y) {
    if (x is CollectionViewGroup xGroup && y is CollectionViewGroup yGroup) {
      return xGroup.Items.Count > yGroup.Items.Count ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```